# Spring's AntPathMatcher matching behavior with linux paths

Tags: java, regex, spring, ant

I came across this weird behavior from [AntPathMatcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html), which I isolated in the unit test below:

```
@Test
    public void testAntPathMacherPotentiallyBrokenForNix() throws IOException {
        AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("properties/RESOURCE_TEST.properties"); // there's a RESOURCE_TEST.properties under a directory 'properties'
        String localPath = resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath();

        Assert.assertThat(antPathMatcher.match("*.properties", localPath), is(true));

        String nixPath = "/local/app/instances/properties/RESOURCE_TEST.properties";

        Assert.assertThat(antPathMatcher.match("*.properties", nixPath), is(true));
}
```

The 2nd assertion fails, but shouldn't both assertions above be true?

What am I missing? (not that I really must use AntPathMatcher, I'm just curious)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce that, but in Spring 3, both versions fail (I'm not touching 2.5 ever again :-)).

Reason: you can't start a path with a wildcard, you need a root to anchor.

Use this pattern: `/**/*.properties`, and at least in Spring 3, both tests will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`antPathMatcher.setPathSeparator(System.getProperty("file.separator")) ;`